# android: How to implement hardware accelerated image eraser?

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I have a bitmap whiteboard app drawing above an imageview background. When I draw a CLEAR paint on top

```
mo_ink.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

or any PorterDuff method, the rendering has a horrible black border while drawing. Disabling hardware acceleration makes the app unusable.

How can I implement a background eraser without the hardware rendering errors?

Edit: I have that slightly wrong. PorterduffMOde CLEAR draws a black path that renders clear on completion. Any other Porterduff method I've tried renders a black bounding box around the path. Ideally I'd like the drawn line to be immediately transparent, drawing the background bitmap masked to the path, but applying a suitable shader would result in the black border. Any solutions? I can't work out what Rasterizer does or if it'll help!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: Sadly no as I need 10 Rep before I can post images! If you think of drawing a path in the API FingerPaint demo, imagine bounding squares of black around the path you are drawing. That's what I'm seeing on my ASUS TF101.

Comment: upvoted this question a bit, you should be able to add an image now :)

Comment: Thanks! The attached mockup shows a grid background ImageView and a custom DrawView on top based on the Finger Paint API demo drawing bezier paths. Setting the Porterduff drawing modes causes a black bounding square around the path. I guess this is because the system draws the path as an OGL texture, and then that's composited. I don't know if the Rasterizer can help, or if there's another way to get a background rather than an underlying image??

Comment: If the problem is resolved when you remove the background ImageView, you could consider drawing the background in your own `onDraw()`-method instead (using `drawBitmap()` or similar).

Comment: Good suggestion. Sadly it still has the funky blackness. I guess it's a limitation of the hardware accelerated rendering at this point.

Comment: Could very well be. Maybe you can work around it by drawing to a mask when using the eraser?